React-infinite-Scroller duplicates initial data only when using filters
I have an order list page where it displays a list of orders. I don't want to load all data at once so I tried to implement and infinite scroller component. I also have filters which will called filtered data based on API. My currently problem is, for example, I enter the orderlist page, so at initial , it will load the first 10 orders ( I set the API to call 10 first) and as I scroll down the infinite scroller will make its magic and works normally. From here, if I tried the other tab filters , it also works perfect normally. However, my problem appears if at initial when I first enter the page then I click a tab filter ( different when before I didn`t click any tab filter and scroll down ) , it automatically duplicates the filtered data and as I went back to default , it also duplicates data. I have tried many ways and I am still new in React and API, any ideas on how to to fix this specific problem.
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState("Overview");
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({ status: null, searchword: null ,startDate:null, lastDate:null});
  const [orderlist, setOrderList] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const user = useLiveQuery(() => db.currentuser.toArray()) ?? [];
  const [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState(1); // Track current page number
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
  

  const fetchOrderList = async (page) => {
    if (loading) return;
  
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      if (user && user.length > 0) {
        const currentOutlet = user[0].currentoutlet;
        let url = `http://placeholder/api/v1/Order?outletid=${currentOutlet}&pagenum=${page}&pagesize=10`;

        
        
        if (filters.status) {
          
          url += `&status=${filters.status}`;
        }
        if (filters.searchword) {
          
          url += `&searchword=${filters.searchword}`;
        }
        if (filters.startDate) {
          url += `&startdate=${filters.startDate}`;
        }
        if (filters.lastDate) {
          url += `&lastdate=${filters.lastDate}`;
        }
  
        const orderlistResponse = await fetch(url);
        
        if (!orderlistResponse.ok) {
          throw new Error("Order list fetch failed");
        }
        const orderData = await orderlistResponse.json();

        

        if (orderData.length === 0 || !orderData ) {
          setHasMore(false);
          setLoading(false);
        } else {
          console.log("b4page" , page)
          setOrderList((prevData) => [
            ...(prevData ?? []),
            ...orderData,
          ]);
            
          
         
          setPageNum(page + 1); // Increment page number
          setHasMore(orderData.length === 10);
          setLoading(false);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setHasMore(false);
      console.error("There was a problem with fetching the order list:", error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    
    fetchOrderList(pageNum);
  }, [filters ]);

  console.log("orderlist", orderlist)
  const ChipStatus = (status) => {
    switch (status) {
      case 'Cancelled':
        return 'bg-red-100 text-red-900';
      case 'Delivered':
        return 'bg-green-100 text-green-900';
      case 'Submitted':
        return 'bg-gray-300 text-gray-900';
      default:
        return 'bg-yellow-100 text-yellow-700';
    }
  };

  const TabHeader = [
    {
      label: "Overview",
      value: "Overview"
    },
    {
      label: "Submitted",
      value: "Submitted"
    },
    {
      label: "In-Transit",
      value: "In-Transit"
    },
    {
      label: "Delivered",
      value: "Delivered"
    },
    {
      label: "Cancelled",
      value: "Cancelled"
    },
  ];

  const handleTabChange = (tabValue) => {
    
    setOrderList([]);
      setPageNum(1)
    setActiveTab(tabValue);
    switch (tabValue) {
      case "Submitted":
        setFilters({ ...filters, status: "Submitted" });
        break;
      case "In-Transit":
        setFilters({ ...filters, status: "In-Transit" });
        break;
      case "Delivered":
        setFilters({ ...filters, status: "Delivered" }); 
        break;
      case "Cancelled":
        setFilters({ ...filters, status: "Cancelled" });
        break;
      case "Overview":
        setFilters({ ...filters, status: null });
        break;
      default :
      return;
    }
  };
  


  

    

this is how I use React-Infinite-Scroller in the jsx
 <InfiniteScroll
          pageStart={1}
          loadMore={() => fetchOrderList(pageNum)}
          hasMore={hasMore}
          loader={<Spinner key={0} className='mx-auto my-10' />}
          useWindow={false} 
          threshold={10} 
        >


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
